# Parse Error in PHP with MongoDB

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I'm trying to query a mongodb database with the _id stored in a session variable...

getting the _id and store as session variable:

```
$_SESSION['user']['userid']=$user['_id']->{'$id'};
```

querying db - error on this line:

```
$user=collection->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($_SESSION['user']['userid'])));
```

can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `$user=$collection->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($_SESSION['user']['userid'])));` You missed a `$` infront of collection

Comment: Now I get a Notice: array to string conversion

Comment: Are you getting that on your `echo` statement ?

Comment: Replace `echo` with `print_r`. That is because an array can't be echoed all together.

Comment: You need to `json_encode` the array and then pass it off.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$users= $mongo->my_db->users;
$user = $users->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($_SESSION['user']['userid']));
print_r($user);

?>
```